# Launch arguments (NSDoubleLocalizedStrings, NSShowNonLocalizedStrings) don't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, localization

I'm trying to use the launch arguments such as `NSDoubleLocalizedStrings` and `NSShowNonLocalizedStrings` to test localization in my Objective-C project. For some reason I couldn't get neither of them to work. I tried to set both arguments on launch and options in scheme settings:[image]
 [image]
Also I've checked `NSUserDefaults` keys and they both are `YES`. But the arguments still don't work.

To make sure it's not an XCode bug I've created absolutely new single-view project on Objective-C and Swift with one label on the view. Both projects had empty `Localizable.strings` files and the code in these projects was the following:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Some text", nil);
}
@end
```

and

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = NSLocalizedString("Some text", comment: "")
    }
}
```

The result looked like this:

[image]

So here are the questions:

1) What could be the reasons launch arguments don't work in my Objective-C project?

2) Why `NSDoubleLocalizedStrings` argument doesn't work in Swift?

Answer (score 3):

Spending couple days on investigation and deleting gradually all the files and frameworks from my Objective-C project I figured out that the reason was in `AFNetworking` library. The issue is described [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3303). If you want to use `AFNetworking` in your project and debug the localization issues you can add such lines to `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"NSDoubleLocalizedStrings"];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"NSShowNonLocalizedStrings"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

On *second* launch of the app you’ll see those launch arguments working.

The answer for the second question about why `NSDoubleLocalizedStrings` argument doesn't work in Swift is that it's probably a bug in XCode. It might be connected with macros which are not supported in Swift, and `NSLocalizedString` is actually a macro. Therefore I've created a bug on [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/32441829).